# Flipping Views in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

In my SwiftUI app, I have an Image:

[image]

I added this image using:

```
Image("shoe_test")
 .resizable()
 .frame(width: 275, height: 275)
 .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 30))
```

However, I would like to flip this image in the opposite direction, like:

[image: Image 2]

For this, I haven't tried anything, but I had no luck with rotationEffect, and I can't get my head over this, Any help is greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
.rotation3DEffect(.degrees(180), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
```

[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/rotation3deffect(_:axis:anchor:anchorz:perspective:))

With the `rotation3DEffect` you can rotate your image in all 3 Dimensions.

- rotating along the `x` axis will flip the image top/bottom
- rotating along the `y` axis will mirror it right/left
- rotating along the `z` axis will flip and mirror it.

Answer (score 11):

It can be done with scale

```
.scaleEffect(x: -1, y: 1)  // flip horizontally

.scaleEffect(x: 1, y: -1)  // flip vertically
```